# Cant switch tasks. Only the last far call seems to work

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to write program which will switch tasks. Everything seems to work properly, but one thing:

```
IRQ0_handler:
push    eax


push screen_selector
pop es

db    9ah        ; far call TSS_1:00
dw    00
dw    TSS_4

db    9ah        ; far call TSS_1:00
dw    00
dw    TSS_2

db    9ah        ; far call TSS_1:00
dw    00
dw    TSS_3

mov    al,20h
out    20h,al

pop    eax
iret
```

This irq handler should switch tasks, but it seems that it calls only the last one. Here's code of one of the tasks (all of them are practically the same, different tasks should display different chars)

```
   TaskOne:

push es
push screen_selector
pop es

mov ah, 1bh
mov al, '1'

mov es:[di], ax
add di, 2
pop es
iret
jmp TaskOne
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing all the code. Btw, I'm not sure all registers are properly saved/restored.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i should've wrote earlier. Problem is solved. It was just trouble with getting chars printed. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code actually should work. It was just trouble with getting chars printed.